# Run 2 MEAN js project on same ubuntu system

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mean-stack, mean

I want to run more than one MEAN js 0.4.2 project using grunt.
First project is running properly by second project giving below error:-

```
       [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
       Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process.
       Warning:  Use --force to continue.
```

change port in /config/env/default.js

```
      port: process.env.PORT || 3002,
```

Please help.I have changed default port(/config/env/default.js) from 3000 to 3002 but still giving same error.

Comment: share the code please.

Comment: I have added the port code above.The second project is copy of first project with port change for review purpose.

Comment: try to print `process.env.PORT` before accessing it. I think that it is not `null`, that why application is not taking port `3002`.

Comment: or, try changing it `port: 3002`

Comment: I have checked for  port:  3002  but still getting same error.

Comment: Try to run `node server.js` instead of `nodemon` . Sorry, issue is with nodemon, instead of node application.

Comment: I have searched 35729 in my Project folder it belongs to livereload module on nodejs,but dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks alot its working with node server.js .I was running with grunt.

Comment: my repo not enough to vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the nodemon, two instances of `nodemon` tries to run on same port.
Try to run

```
node server.js
```

Or, 
you can try to configure nodemon as well.

https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon/issues/21#issuecomment-28116032